# How to show that the following limit converges to some order of 1/n term .

Tags: real-analysis, probability

How to prove that $$[e^{t\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{np}}}-1-t\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{np}}-\frac{1}{2}t^2(\frac{1-p}{np})]\cdot p \\+[e^{-t\sqrt{\frac{p}{n(1-p)}}}-1+t\cdot\sqrt{\frac{p}{n{(1-p)}}}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot t^2 (\frac{p}{n(1-p)})](1-p)$$ converges to some order of $\frac{1}{n}$ term . where $0 \leq p\leq 1$ and $t$ is a parameter which can take any real value.

Answer (score 2):

If you let $a=t\sqrt{(1-p)/p}$ and $b=t\sqrt{p/(1-p)}$, then let $\epsilon=1/\sqrt{n}$, then you are looking at $\exp(a\epsilon)$ and $exp(-b\epsilon)$.

Assume $n$ is large, so $\epsilon$ is small, but $p$ is not too near 0 nor 1.

The Taylor series for

$$\exp(a\epsilon)=1+a\epsilon+\frac{a^2\epsilon^2}{2}+\frac{a^3\epsilon^3}{6}+O(\epsilon^4)$$

You have removed the first three terms.  Similarly for the second line with $b$.  So the result will be

$$\frac{a^3\epsilon^3}{6}p-\frac{b^3\epsilon^3}{6}(1-p)+O(\epsilon^4)\\
=\frac{t^3}{6n^{3/2}}[(1-p)^{3/2}p^{-1/2}-p^{3/2}(1-p)^{-1/2}]+O(1/n^2)\\
=\frac{t^3(1-2p)}{6n^{3/2}\sqrt{p(1-p)}}+O(1/n^2)$$

Comment: If $p$ gets smaller than $O(1/n)$, then the first exponential gets very large.  If $p$ gets close to 1, the expression approaches $-t^2/2n$.